# React/NextJS {" "} before an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am using VS Code with Prettier but when I save:

```
Hello: <Name>World<//Name>
```

It changes to:

```
Hello:{" "}
<Name>World</Name>
```

It also does it when I have just:

```
Hello <Name>World<//Name>
```

Somehow it does not do it here though:

```
<h1 className={styles.title}>
    Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
</h1>
```

The `Hello World` examples are surrounding by a `<p>` element.

Why and what are the purposes of this?

Comment: It seems it's a worldwide issue that didn't solve yet.
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223

Comment: Well that just sucks and makes you not want to have it enabled.

Comment: sometimes it means the whitespace may not be recognized by the html so it adds the " "

Comment: It's weird because it did not add it in the default nextjs line: Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a> so not sure why it picks and chooses. So there is no way around this?